# How to convert special value in R data-frame to NA?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a `data-frame` containing `#` as a missing value in multiple columns. How can I convert all such `#`s to `NA`s?

Comment: `read.table(file, na.strings = "#")`

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven. What if the data is already present in `data-frame`? (assuming I only have access to `data-frame` and not `file`)

Comment: Then try `df[df == "#"] <- NA`

Comment: Sure. Thanks! :) [you can write both the tips as an answer to this question and I will be happy to accept it]

Comment: https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/makemeNA.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a few ways.  One is to re-read the file in with the `na.strings` argument set to `"#"`

```
read.table(file, na.strings = "#")
```

Another would be to just change the values in the data frame  `df` with

```
df[df == "#"] <- NA
```

Answer (score 3):

```
is.na(dat) <- dat == "#"
```

will do the trick (where `dat` is the name of your data frame).

Answer (score 2):

I have written [a function `makemeNA`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/makemeNA.R) that is part of [my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

The function looks like this (in case you don't want to get the package just for this function):

```
makemeNA <- function (mydf, NAStrings, fixed = TRUE) {
  if (!isTRUE(fixed)) {
    mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) gsub(NAStrings, "", x))
    NAStrings <- ""
  }
  mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) type.convert(
    as.character(x), na.strings = NAStrings))
  mydf
}
```

Usage would be:

```
makemeNA(df, "#")
```

---

Get the package with:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")
```